# Aptana folding for javascript, configure hover

Tags: javascript, hover, aptana, configure, folding

I have set Preferences>Aptana Studio>Editors>JavaScript to "Enable Folding" of "Comments". When I hover over the "+" sign in the left margin of a folded comment, Aptana automatically pops up a yellow window displaying the entire text of the folded comment.
  Is there a way to turn off this automatic pop-up?